# python soappy add header

Tags: python, soap, header, soappy

I have the following PHP example code:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://example.com/example.wsdl");

$h = Array();
array_push($h, new SoapHeader("http://example2.com/example2/", "h", "v"));
$client->__setSoapHeaders($h);

$s = $client->__soapCall('Op', $data);
```

My question: what's the SOAPpy equivalent for the SoapHeader() and __setSoapHeaders() part?

#### Related question

- [How to add header while making soap request using soappy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481313/how-to-add-header-while-making-soap-request-using-soappy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example  using [suds](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/wiki/Documentation#SOAPHEADERS) library (an alternative to SOAPpy). It assumes that the custom header is not defined in the wsdl.

```
from suds.client      import Client
from suds.sax.element import Element

client = Client("http://example.com/example.wsdl")

# <tns:h xmlns:tns="http://example2.com/example2/">v</tns:h>
tns = ("tns", "http://example2.com/example2/")
h = Element('h', ns=tns).setText('v')
client.set_options(soapheaders=h) 
#
s = client.service.Op(data)
```